# Why does an RDS instance take > 2 hours to start?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

New to AWS and RDS. Created a test `db.t3.micro` DB instance, used it for a few hours, then stopped it.

Today I started it, and over 2 hours later it's still showing "Starting...". Is this normal?

There is one database with one table with one row on that instance. The only thing I can see in the logs is: *"Recovery of the DB instance has started. Recovery time will vary with the amount of data to be recovered."* (from roughly the time I gave the *Start* command via AWS console).

#### Update: the server finally started in 3 hrs 37 mins

Comment: Sometimes it's just the status that failed to update.  Try actually connecting to it, and bounce it again if it still isn't up.

Comment: Tried that multiple times (assuming the server address doesn't change between restarts), & it actually doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Stopping and starting a DB will make AWS automatically create a snapshot (I was told during the AWS Sys admin course). Creating snapshots is very fast usually, but sometimes there are very large delays. My personal view is that this is probably some form of congestion on AWS' side, but I don't have an official comment to verify this.

Note that RDS instances aren't really ment to be shutdown and started up again. They're really ment to run continously. Starting/stopping instances has only been possible since 2017! https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/.

My personal experience is that it's faster to create a snapshot and start a new instance from that, if possible in your use-case.

Edit: To clarify, 2 hours is NOT typical. In my experience a 500Gb DB will usually be restored in about 20-25 minutes. I'm afraid you're unlucky.

Comment: _"only been possible since 2017"_ : yeah, found that out during my search :-). So you suggest just waiting for it?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other real option. I've had a DB restore take 6 hours, when my  8 previous tests took 21 minutes. It's the risk of letting AWS handle everything.

Comment: I just noticed something. I was doing a routine data migrations and my throughput has been abysmal since 2020-02-04T12:35 UTC. Have you been performing the restoring in the same timeframe? That would confirm my congestion theory even more...

Comment: My _Start_ (restore) of the server started around _04 Feb 2020 11:21:30 GMT_, so close to when you were doing your migration... ultimately started in 3 hrs 37 mins.

Comment: Good lord. Can I configure my instance to not make a snapshot ever?

Comment: @daraul, the instances making a snapshot is no issue. It won't impact performance since they're performed on EBS level by placing mark at a specific point in time. The main point is that there might be latency in creation, which is why it takes a long time.

Comment: Right, that's why I wanted to disable that functionality completely. I spent around 30-40 minutes, today, waiting for an RDS instance to start, and then stop.